# How can I fix brush lag in Texture Paint?

Tags: texturing

It seems to be lagging in the viewport, and I don't know why. I just downloaded 2.79, since 2.78 seemed to have the same issue. I do not believe earlier versions had this issue beyond that.

If I use the Paint mode in the UV Editor, it doesn't lag at all. How can I fix this?

EDIT: It's been a long time, but I had a PC with 16GB of RAM and a 970. (I now have a much better PC.)

For the record, I tried using low poly vs high poly, and the size of the texture didn't seem to matter. (I literally did the same for both versions and it was still nada.)

I haven't tried it on newer versions of Blender, or my new system, but I will be doing so soon. Since this is a high traffic question, I'll update if I have any issues/solutions.

Comment: Usually brush lag in the viewport is caused by too much pixel data being projected at once - at a rate that is unsustainable for viewport performance. It could be that your textures are too hi-res, that you are too far zoomed out (causing a single brush stroke to have influence over a vast texture area), or some combination of the two. I don't know anything about your hardware specs but of course insufficient RAM would also lead to viewport performance problems.

Comment: could be a number of reasons :
- too much geometry in viewport
- too high-res material texture
- too high-res brush texture
- too big brush size
- too small spacing in the brush stroke properties
- too many applications open at the same time
- too low-end hardware

- do you think some of these fit your conditions ?

Comment: Nope. I have 16GB RAM, and a 970. I have 8 cores, too. Also, it does it even was a basic cube and 256 texture. Ty, though!

Comment: I suffer from this as well (in Blender 2.83). There seems to be some weird threshold. When zoomed in, it's very snappy, no lag at all. But at some point when I am zooming out, each click takes about 20 seconds to go through.

Comment: I have the same problem (Blender 2.83, 32 gigs ram, RTX 2080 TI, ssd). My computer is beefy enough but when the brush size is too big, it gets very slow. Texture size is 4096x4096 px.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the *Window Draw Method* to *Full* under *User Preferences* seemed to fix the lagging in my case, even though I'm not sure how this could impact other things. But after changing it once, I was able to set the draw method back to *Automatic* and still be able to paint without lag. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56154)

Comment: @VRM Technically, this does attempt to answer the question. It is a short answer, and really more of a suggestion than a full answer - but it still is technically an answer.

Comment: @X-27 This is one of those edge cases where it is clearly better suited as a comment but does technically sort of answer the question. Take a look at the last part of the automated comment generated by the review.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my mistake, this is my first time answering to a question in Stack Overflow. I realized that my last answer about toggling *Only Render* didn't actually fix the problem op was talking about, so I changed it to a workaround I saw on the Blender Artists forum.

Answer (score 1):

Closing all workspace areas which display the texture or the texture image and using only one area can help reduce texture paint lag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you're perceiving as lag isn't actually lag, it's a property of the default "space" stroke of the brush.  Basically it's set to draw every so often you reach a spacing point. This is the default setup of Blender.

If you look under the "Stroke" option in the top bar, you'll see a setting "Stroke Method". If it's set to "Space" then try setting the "Spacing" below that to 1%. You should now find that the brush now seems to paint instantaneously. In reality, it's not any faster, it's just that the spacing of control points of the stroke is different.